# How do Native mobile app development with JavaScript work?

Tags: react-native, nativescript, native

In the last few years there's been lots of solution that claim to let you create "Native" mobile apps with existing Web Technologies (HTML, CSS and JS). Frameworks like React Native and NativeScript that I know.

I am a web developer and as far as I know you cannot write Android/iOS apps using JavaScript. I can kinda map in my head how HTML and CSS translates to native apps, but about JavaScript I don't understand.

Do they transform language to platform-specific language? Or do they ship a JS engine with your app to production?

Let's say I have a ReactNative project and this is part of my app:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

const YourApp = () => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}>
      <Text onClick={() => {
        const a = 2 + 2;
        const b = Math.random();
        doSomethingWith(a * b);
      }>
        Try editing me! 
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default YourApp;
```

In the above code, what does happen behind the curtains at framework level? For every part? (JSX part (View), those styles (CSS) and when I click on Text (JS))

Comment: Those frameworks typically just wrap your webapp into a WebView component inside the native app and provide some special calls to communicate with the native app.

Comment: @derpirscher are you sure about that? I guess not. That was the old solutions (back in 2010-2015), solutions like cordova webview. Now they are actually building "Native" apps